# Unable to install 'IfxPy' package

Tags: python, package, git-bash

I am trying to install 'IfxPy' package using pip command on Git-Bash but getting below error. Tried adding wheel to. Still unable to install.

```
$ pip3 install ifxpy
Collecting ifxpy
  Using cached IfxPy-3.0.5.tar.gz (155 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ifxpy
  Building wheel for ifxpy (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for ifxpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\gsampath\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\gsampath\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d9wyx3hw\\ifxpy_28fd8dfdd9ff4259b237248d082433ad\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\gsampath\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d9wyx3hw\\ifxpy_28fd8dfdd9ff4259b237248d082433ad\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\gsampath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-3jsyuxx7
.
.
.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\gsampath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d9wyx3hw\ifxpy_28fd8dfdd9ff4259b237248d082433ad\libs /LIBPATH:C:CSDK\lib /LIBPATH:c:\users\gsampath\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\gsampath\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" iclit09b.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_IfxPy build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\ifxpyc.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\IfxPy.cp38-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\IfxPy.cp38-win32.lib
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'iclit09b.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that no wheel is available for this package and it has an underlying dependency, hence pip will try to build it in your system.

I searched the missing lib in the Installation and got the following entry:

> [IBM iclit09b.lib reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.odbc.doc/ids_odbc_023.htm)

You may found other ways of installing it, but you first need the low level library prior to installing the Python wrapper around it.